# how to assess student experiences from research opportunities?

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I teach a Course for Undergraduate Research Experience (CURE) on marine soundscapes and communication. Throughout the semester each student leads a project of their choosing using my own databases, participate in all the components of research, and at the end they write a blog describing their experiences. I want to understand if my course is helping them to find their STEM identity (it doesn't have to be in the marine sciences),  what kinds of  analysis are available to use their blogs to examine this question and use it to improve my course.

Comment: Are you now at the end of the course or is the for a future course?

Comment: Probably anything formal here is overkill - just read the blogs and take notes or do and outro interview.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the learning outcomes of research degrees. Universities or accreditation bodies usually spell out what they expect of students who have a higher degree. You can then mark students based on whether they have demonstrated these outcomes (or come close).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a question on assessing an educational intervention. The right people to get on board for this are education professionals, which most universities have of course.

(Having gone through this sort of exercise, I will unambiguously state that while I thought "it can't be so hard to make that assessment myself", my position now is "I had no idea how to do that, and I'm glad that I asked professionals in the area". If you teach in marine sciences, you're unlikely to have the background to actually do the data in your blogs any justice and/or to come to conclusions that are statistically valid. If you intend to publish your experiences, you might also run into problems with privacy concerns for which you need ORB approval -- also a reason to have education professionals be part of whatever you want to do.)